# How to have different options for sets of parameters VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am writing a simple console program that is a calculator and I am using a function to do the actual calculating and I need for some 2 numbers and for others 3 numbers to be sent across in the parameters for the function, and I can't find anywhere how to have different sets of parameters. It may be that you can't do it but it is always good to ask before giving up!

This is the first line of the function so far

```
Function Calculate(n1 As Decimal, n2 As Decimal, n3 As Decimal, calcOption As Char)
```

Thanks in advance, James

Comment: You can define multiple methods with the same name, but different sets of parameters: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/311330/how-to-overloading-methods-in-visual-basic--net-or-in-visual-basic-200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ParamArray

```
Function Calculate(calcOption As Char, ParamArray numbers() As Decimal) As Decimal
    Select Case calcOption
        Case "s"c ' sum
            Return numbers.Sum()
        Case "p"c ' product
            Return numbers.Aggregate(Function(n1, n2) n1 * n2)
        Case "d"c ' division
            Return numbers.Aggregate(Function(n1, n2) n1 / n2)
        Case "m"c ' minus
            Return numbers.Aggregate(Function(n1, n2) n1 - n1)
        Case Else
            'etc.
            Return 0
    End Select
End Function
```

Usage

```
Dim product = Calculate("p"c, 2, 3, 4)
' 24
Dim sum = Calculate("s"c, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
' 35
```

Special case for 0 or 1 parameters, but you can figure that out.